# How to bind a .click() event only the container?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, onclick

I want the user entry to open up accordion-style, but a `.click()` event is triggered even if I click on any other element inside the red box - the text, the image, etc.

I'd like to only have the "outer" whitespace cause the event to trigger.

How do I accomplish this?

```js
$('#box').click(function(e) {
  console.log(e);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="box" style="width:80%;background:red;">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td><img src="http://i.imgur.com/NaCmGyX.jpg" style="width:50px;height:50px;border-radius:50%;"></td>
      <td><b>John McDerpenstein</b></td>
      <td><p>
      A blurb goes here
      </p></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/x71fuuxj/)

Comment: Please provide your code along with a JSFiddle.

Comment: the event is propagating to the parent element.

Comment: May I suggest just a very simple modification to your script for testing purposes: Please change `console.log(e)` to something like `console.log('test')`, otherwise some browsers (including mine) hang for a second or two and it is a bit frustrating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the `target` property of the event to see if it was the `#box` element directly by using `is()`:

```
$('#box').click(function(e) {
    if ($(this).is(e.target))
        console.log(e);
});
```

[**Updated fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/x71fuuxj/2/)

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<body>
<div id="box" style="width:80%;background:red;">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td><img src="http://i.imgur.com/NaCmGyX.jpg" style="width:50px;height:50px;border-radius:50%;"></td>
      <td><b>John McDerpenstein</b></td>
      <td><p>
      A blurb goes here
      </p></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
<script src="jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>
<script>
$('img').click(function(e) {
  console.log(e);
});
</script>

</html>
```

Comment: what's the outer white space?

Comment: did you mean the image?

Comment: Please read the question carefully before answering. The questions you asked in your comments can both be answered by checking out the original question itself.

Answer (score 0):

Just check the `e.target.id` to see if it matches the specific `id` of the outer box you want. Example below:

```js
$('#box').click(function(e) {
  if (e.target.id === "box")
    console.log('click');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="box" style="width:80%;background:red;">this is the outer box
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td><img src="http://i.imgur.com/NaCmGyX.jpg" style="width:50px;height:50px;border-radius:50%;"></td>
      <td><b>John McDerpenstein</b></td>
      <td><p>
      A blurb goes here
      </p></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add the event to the parent container you will have to stop the **propagation** on all the **child elements** that will not need a click event .

**Example :**

since `#box` has the click and box is your **container**

you will need to give image an id and stop the propagation

```
$('#imageID').click(function(e){

e.stopPropagation();

})
```

With the example above when you click the image nothing will happen , but if you click the red container then your event will log.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to prevent the event if the click is done on child:

```
$('#box').click(function(e) {
    if (!$(this).is(e.target)) {
        return e.preventDefault()
    }

    // code here (or nothing, href="" action)

});
```